# Finding the nullity of Matrix A (m x n)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been given a question to find the nullity of A. 
A is a m x n matrix, what are the possible values of nullity(A)? 
Values given as options are :

a) (m-1) ≤ nullity(A)

b) nullity(A) ≥ m

c) nullity(A) ≤ n

d) nullity(A)=0

And all options seems to be true to me. I am sure about options c and d. But options a) and b) are also holding true for few matrix examples.

For example :

[image: nullity is greater than number of rows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Rank-Nullity theorem**:
>
> If there is a matrix $A$  with $m$ rows and $n$ columns over a field, then
>   $$Rank ( A) + Nullity (A) = n $$
>
> ---

${}$

---

> Also $Rank(A)\leq min\{m,n\}$

Let $n \lt m$, then $Rank(A) \leq n$

**Case I:** If in a matrix $A$, $Rank (A)=n$, then $Nullity (A)=0$

**Case II:** If in a matrix $A$, $0 \leq Rank (A) \lt n$, then $Nullity (A)\leq n$

Let $n \gt m$, then $Rank(A) \leq m$

**Case I:**  If in a matrix $A$, $Rank (A)=m$, then $Nullity (A)=n-m$

**Case II:** If in a matrix $A$, $0 \leq Rank (A) \lt m$, then $Nullity (A)\leq n-m$

---

---

Although your given example satisfy both the option $a$ and $b$, but from one particular example you can't conclude that those statements are true for all.

Comment: Thanks @nmasanta . But in question it is asked to find the possible values? Option a and b can't be true for all, but it's possible.

Comment: Yes, for particular cases.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. :)

Comment: You are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the nullity of a matrix is the dimension of the space of vectors for which 
$$A\vec x = \vec 0$$
So, for some matrices, the only vector $\vec x$ for which $A\vec x = \vec 0$ is the zero vector itself. In those cases, the matrix has linearly independent column and has $null(A)=0$. This is a very special property, and not all matrices have them.
We know that for an $m\times n$ matrix, the input vector $\vec x$ must have dimension $n$, so the maximum dimension of the space of vectors for which $A\vec x = \vec 0$ is clearly $n$ because $\vec x$ is only $n$-dimensional.

The nullity of a matrix is hence inclusively bounded between $0$ and $n$.

Comment: So you are saying that option a and b are not correct?

Comment: @nbalodi all of them are possible for some matrix but c is the only one that is always true.

Comment: Thanks @ D.R. I got it.